# Laravel Collection Extended Relationship (Pass or Fail)

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I'm using Laravel 5.6. I have three models: User, Attempt, Assessment. I need to find out which Assessments a user has or has not passed. As a user takes an assessment an Attempt model will be saved with the is_passing true or false boolean. Below is my database structure.

```
User
ID | name

Attempt
ID | assessment_id | user_id | is_passing (bool)

Assessment
ID | name
```

I'm working in the User.php model file and trying to create a collection to be able to loop through assessments as such

```
@foreach($user->assessmentsPassOrFail as $assessment)
    @if($assessment->passed)
        {{ $assessment->name }}
    @else
       <a href="link to assessment">{{ $assessment->name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

I have the following in my User.php, but it needs to be tweaked to show all Assessments (pass or fail) and not just passing.

```
public function attempts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Attempt');
}

public function assessmentsPassOrFail(){
        return $this->attempts()->with('assessment')->where('is_passing', 1);
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help! Been beating my head against a wall for the past 2 days on this!

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `where('is_passing', 1)`, which is only finding those that are passing. Remove that statement. You may need to put `->get()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Assessment`, where `Attempt` is acting as a joining table. See Laravel's documentation here, specifically: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

In your case, I would rewrite your assessments function to reflect the nature of its relationship with a `User`:

```
public function assessments()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Assessments', 'Attempt')->withPivot('is_passing');
}
```

The `belongsToMany` method relies on some Laravel conventions for table and column names to work out of the box, but all of these can be defined specifically for cases that don't follow their expected conventions. In this case, Laravel would expect the joining table to be named `assessment_user`, and would expect the other table names to be plural and all lower case. So you may have to explicitly define the parameters in the `belongsToMany` method for it to work properly. See details here: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_belongsToMany

The `withPivot` method defines which fields from the joining table should be retrieved when using this relationship. You can now retrieve this value like so:

```
$user = App\Models\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->assessments as $a) {
    echo $a->pivot->is_passing;
}
```

Hope this helps!